# SwiftUI - Multicomponent picker selection style

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I have a problem where I try to build a picker with three components. The selection (the grey part) seems to be off. Is there a way to turn it off or customize it so that I get one selection for all three components?

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in

        VStack{
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Picker("", selection: $firstSelection) {
                    ForEach(0..<numbers.count) { index in
                        Text("\(numbers[index])")
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: 150, alignment: .center)


                Picker("", selection: $secondSelection) {
                    ForEach(0..<numbers.count) { index in
                        Text("\(numbers[index])")
                    }
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()

                Picker("", selection: $thirdSelection) {
                    ForEach(0..<numbers.count) { index in
                        Text("\(numbers[index])")
                    }
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width/3, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                .clipped()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the picker. [image]

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969730/how-to-change-uipickerview-width-with-multiple-pickers-in-swiftui.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks, but that is for UIPicker not SwiftUI's picker...

Comment: Hello @xxFlashxx,

I had a simpler problem, did you find solution?