# UIPickerView with UIViewRepresentable does not fill the whole width

Tags: xcode, swiftui, uipickerview, uiviewrepresentable

Unfortunately, when I create a UIPickerView in SwiftUI with UIViewRepresenable it doesn't fill the whole screen. I've also tried giving it a lot of frame modifiers, but nothing worked. Does anyone have a solution for this or knows why the width of the entire screen is not filled with the picker? Best regards

This is the Code:

```
struct MultiComponentsPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var hours: Int
    @Binding var minutes: Int
    @Binding var seconds: Int
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPickerView {
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = context.coordinator
        pickerView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        
        return pickerView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPickerView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        
        let parent: MultiComponentsPicker
        
        init(_ parent: MultiComponentsPicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 6
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            if component == 0 {
                return 24
            }
            
            else if component == 1 {
                return 1
            }
            
            else if component == 2 {
                return 60
            }
            
            else if component == 3 {
                return 1
            }
            
            else if component == 4 {
                return 60
            }
            
            else if component == 5 {
                return 1
            }
            
            return 0
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            if component == 0 {
                return "\(row)"
            }
            
            else if component == 1 {
                return "Std."
            }
            
            else if component == 2 {
                return "\(row)"
            }
            
            else if component == 3 {
                return "Min."
            }
            
            else if component == 4 {
                return "\(row)"
            }
            
            else if component == 5 {
                return "Sek."
            }
            
            
            return ""
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if component == 0 {
                parent.hours = Int(row.description)!
            }
            
            else if component == 2 {
                parent.minutes = Int(row.description)!
            }
            
            else if component == 4 {
                parent.seconds = Int(row.description)!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And thats what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could you also include the SwiftUI code where `MultiComponentsPicker` is used?

Comment: Just that:  `MultiComponentsPicker(hours: $selectedHours, minutes: $selectedMinutes, seconds: $selectedSeconds)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 150)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969730/how-to-change-uipickerview-width-with-multiple-pickers-in-swiftui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the UIViewRepresentable:

```
    // allows rows to be compressed
    pickerView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    // allows rows to be expanded
    pickerView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
```

in the View:

```
    MultiComponentsPicker(hours: $hours, minutes: $minutes, seconds: $seconds)
        .frame(width: .infinity) // or fixed size
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!! It worked perfectly 